# showing different text view from drop down list in ajax, php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to showing different text view from one drop down list.

```
<select id="selector">
<option value="opt0"  id="opt0">select menu</option>`enter code here`
<option value="opt1"  id="opt1">fruit</option>
<option value="opt2"  id="opt2">vegetable</option>
<option value="opt3"  id="opt3">drink</option>
```

if I choose fruit there are text view a, b

if I choose vegetable there are text view c, d

how ccan I do it with ajax?

Comment: what do you mean by text view? where do you get those a,b,c? what are they? why do you need to use ajax?

Comment: i mean a,b,c just text view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might give you some idea. If I understand your question correctly.

HTML:

```
<select id="selector">
<option value="opt0"  id="opt0">select menu</option>
<option value="opt1"  id="opt1">fruit</option>
<option value="opt2"  id="opt2">vegetable</option>
<option value="opt3"  id="opt3">drink</option>
</select>

<div id="appendHere">

</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('#selector').change(function(){

 var selectValue = $(this).val();
 if(selectValue == 'opt1'){
  $('#appendHere').empty();
  $('#appendHere').append("<input type='text' class='fruit' name='a' />"); 
  $('#appendHere').append("<input type='text' class='fruit' name='b' />"); 

 }else if(selectValue == 'opt2'){
  $('#appendHere').empty();
  $('#appendHere').append("<input type='text' class='vegetable' name='c' />"); 
  $('#appendHere').append("<input type='text' class='vegetable' name='d' />");
 }

});
```

Comment: it works, thank you.. but how to make the input type text between fruit and vegetable not became stack? if i choose option "fruit" input text a and b visible and then if i choose option "drink" input text c and d also visible and stack below input text a and b.

i want to make if i choose option fruit only a and b and option drink only c and d

Comment: @AnitaIntansiaHutagaol it's easy you just need to add `$('#appendHere').empty();`... I think you can do the rest yourself.. =) if this helps you kindly check and mark it up.. thanks =)

Comment: by the way @ShiguriAnemone' how to make writeable inside the input type? i'm trying to input value but can't

Comment: I've checked on it.. and it's writable... you mean getting the value of the textboxes?

Comment: but in my code it's not writeable.. i can't write something in the text box.. is there something wrong?

Comment: @AnitaIntansiaHutagaol maybe you disabled it? do you see any `disabled` attribute in your inputs?

Comment: there is nothing disable attr in my code. make me confused.. :(
or there is something adding code to make it enable to write?

Comment: @AnitaIntansiaHutagaol can you post all of your codes?

Comment: @AnitaIntansiaHutagaol so, what's the solution? it's okay we all do stupid mistakes.. =)

Comment: @AnitaIntansiaHutagaol so you put a new function which is `keypress`... just remove that.

Comment: @AnitaIntansiaHutagaol no problem.. glad to help you... =)